# (Closed) How to plot variations between dates with ggplot in r

Tags: date, ggplot2, bar-chart

| Date | Water stock (Liters/m²) |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-07-20 | 121.45 |
| 2022-07-22 | 116.05 |
| 2022-07-26 | 109.30 |
| 2022-07-27 | 107.10 |
| 2022-08-03 | 99.35 |
| 2022-08-10 | 92.75 |
| 2022-08-25 | 89.50 |
| 2022-08-31 | 87.50 |
| 2022-09-07 | 87.15 |

I have this dataframe and I want to plot with ggplot a barchart that corresponds to the difference of water stock between each date. So the first variation is between the 20 of july and the 22 of july, the next variation is between the 22 of july and the 26 of july and so on.

I know how to calculate the difference of water stock between the dates but I have trouble ploting it nicely.

The problem I encouter is with the x axis. I want my graph to look like this picture. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xFUK.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to plot the dates as factors (so that each subsequent date is a 1-level change regardless of time passed) and right-justify (`just = 0`) to move the bar to the gap between dates:

```r
library(tidyverse)

tribble(~Date, ~stock, 
   "2022-07-20", 121.45,
   "2022-07-22", 116.05,
   "2022-07-26", 109.30,
   "2022-07-27", 107.10,
   "2022-08-03", 99.35,
   "2022-08-10", 92.75,
   "2022-08-25", 89.50,
   "2022-08-31", 87.50,
   "2022-09-07", 87.15 ) |> 
  mutate(Date = factor(Date)) |> 
  ggplot(aes(Date, stock)) +
  geom_col(width = 1, just = 0, colour = "black") +
  ylab("Water stock (Liters/m²)") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = -45, hjust = 0))
```

[image]

Comment: Seems to do the trick. Thank you Andy.

Comment: Great! Do mark closed if this is working for you :)